# JS: Displaying 2 useState that are related to each within the same div

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm pulling from a api for a self project, I'm trying to set up the recipe and the required ingredient to be within the same div box or something similar. Problem is that I'm using .map to pull out both the recipe and ingredient which cause one to be full to be print out before the one. Is there any way for when one recipe to finish printing it'll print the ingredient required with it.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import ErrorAlert from "../components/ErrorAlert";

function PostFormPage() {
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [instructions, setInstructions] = useState([]);
  const [ingrediants, setIngrediants] = useState([]);
  const [numOfRecipe, setNumOfRecipe] = useState(0);

  const handleContentChange = (event) => {
    setContent(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    setIngrediants([]);
    setInstructions([]);
    setNumOfRecipe(0);
    event.preventDefault();
    try{}
    .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          for (let i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
            // For each recipe
            if (
              data.results[i].instructions !== undefined &&
              data.results[i].sections !== undefined
            ) {
              setInstructions((prevArray) => [
                ...prevArray,
                data.results[i].instructions,
              ]);
              setIngrediants((previousArray) => [
                ...previousArray,
                data.results[i].sections,
              ]);
              setNumOfRecipe((numOfRecipe) => numOfRecipe + 1);
            }
          }
        });

      if (response.ok) {
        setSuccess(true);
      } else {
        setError(true);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Server error while creating a new micro post", error);
      setError(true);
    }
  };

  //if (success) return <Navigate to="/" />;

  return (
    <>
      <div className="col-15 col-md-8 col-lg-10">
        {error && <ErrorAlert details={"Failed to save the content"} />}
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="input-group">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Input your recipe here..."
              value={content}
              className="form-control"
              onChange={handleContentChange}
              autoFocus
            />
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
              Search
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div className="col-15 col-md-8 col-lg-10">
        {numOfRecipe !== 0 ? (
          <div className="mt-5">
            {instructions.map((index_instr) => (
              <div className="border mt-5">
                {index_instr.map(
                  (all_instructions) => all_instructions.display_text
                )}
              </div>
            ))}
            {ingrediants.map((sect) => (
              <div>
                {sect.map((comp) => (
                  <div>{comp.components.map((a) => a.raw_text)}</div>
                ))}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ) : (
          <></>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I've try using table but it comes out unportioned and weird.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).